# Write code that uses an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) to create the fibonacci function where indicated

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am trying to write javascript to do a fibonacci sequence. I got the math part but we have to have an array named fibonacciResults and I am unsure on how to use an array named fibonacciResults and initialize it so that fibonacci(0) will be 0 and fibonacci(1) will be 1. Also, If the result (fibonacci(n)) has never been calculated before, calculate the new result recursively and save it in the fibonacciResults array.

```
    document.querySelector('#calculate-fibonacci').addEventListener('click', function () {
      var fibonacci; // Do not declare more variables here.

      // WRITE YOUR fibonacci FUNCTION HERE
      fibonacci = function fibonacci(n) {
         fibonacciResults = [];
         n = Math.round(n);
         if (Number.isFinite(n) && n >= 0) {
            if (n < 2) {
               return n;
            }
            return fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1);
         }
         return 0;
      };

      (function () {
         var whichFibonacciNumber;
         // Get the user's number.
         whichFibonacciNumber = parseInt(document.querySelector('#fibonacci-input').value, 10);
         // Use the fibonacci function to calculate the output.
         document.querySelector('#which-fibonacci-number').textContent = whichFibonacciNumber;
         document.querySelector('#fibonacci-number').textContent = fibonacci(whichFibonacciNumber);
      }());
   }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fibonacci = (function () {
    var cache = {};
    return function (n) {

        var cached = cache[n];
        if (cached) return cached;

        if (n <= 1) return n;
        console.log(n);

        return (cache[n] = fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1));
    };
}());
```